# why closure doesn't work properly on member function?

Tags: f#, closures

If I do it normally, it works as expected (cache the result):

```
      let help = let tmp = printfn "oh no"
                           1+1
                 fun () -> tmp
      help ()
      help ()

      >oh no
```

However if i make it as a member function, it no longer works:

```
    type test =
        { a: float }
        member x.help = 
                  let tmp = printfn "oh no"
                            x.a * 2.
                  fun () -> tmp
        member x.b = x.help ()

    let t = { a = 1. }
    t.b
    t.b

    >oh no
    >oh no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @John said, according to [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997176), your `help` property is equivalent to

```
type test =
     { a: float }
     member x.help with get () = 
              let tmp = printfn "oh no"
                        x.a * 2.
              fun () -> tmp
```

which is a function in disguise so a new `tmp` value is evaluated each time the property is invoked.

To ensure that the property is invoked once, you can create a private helper and use it in type augmentation:

```
type test = { a: float }

/// Create a private helper to make sure 'help' is evaluate once
let private help = 
    printfn "oh no"              
    fun x -> x.a * 2.

/// Create a property using the private helper
type test with
     member x.b = help x
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the real difference -

```
  let help = let tmp = printfn "oh no"
                       1+1
             fun () -> tmp
  printfn "here"
  help ()
  help ()
```

This prints

```
here
oh no
```

So help is actually formed before it is even called.

In the second case, we can read from the spec (8.13.1)

> Furthermore, the following two members are equivalent:
>
> staticopt member ident.opt ident = expr
>
> staticopt member ident.opt ident with get () = expr

I.e. your x.b is actually a function which calls help every time

Comment: a small error worth pointing out, it should print oh no here rather than here oh no

Answer (score 0):

Methods always have an implicit `this` argument so they are always functions. In your case `x` is an argument in the OO code that did not exist in the original.